# GDPR IFrame Cookies - Opt-In necessary?

Tags: internet, software, privacy

A lot of googling didn't help me with the following questions:

Given I own a website which only creates one cookie that identifies a users session - is it okay to embed said website in an `iframe` without prior consent? Accessing the webpage in a logged-out state does not create a cookie, but being logged in makes the value accessible to the websites server / javascript that is loaded in the `iframe`.

Furthermore: given an identifier that is added as a parameter to my webpages url that **identifies the embedding page** (e.g. `www.asd.com` embeds my page `www.mypage.com` with `?id=35235`) - is that GDPR compliant or not?

Comment: GDPR has nothing to do with cookies unless they contain personal data. There is a separate EU law about cookies.

Comment: How does this hold up to eprivacy then? There also was a ruling today in the europe supreme court that declared all cookies no matter the content opt in. Session identifiers are not personal data right?

Comment: as I say, cookies with personal data are subject to GDPR and those without are not. However, all cookies are subject to the cookie law which is a different law than GDPR.